# Restore state of android's search view widget

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-widget, searchview

Im having a search view in my action bar and i want to restore the query after orientation changed. How can I do this?  Setting the query from the bundle using `SearchView.setQuery(query, false);` doesn't work as the searchview sets its query to `""` as soon as it expands.

Heres the relevant code in my `onActivityCreated`:

```
if(savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(BUNDLE_KEY_SEARCH))
    mCurFilter = savedInstanceState.getString(BUNDLE_KEY_SEARCH);
```

And here my `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
savedInstanceState.putString(BUNDLE_KEY_SEARCH, mCurFilter);
super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
```

So how can I restore its state as im not able to do it using `setQuery`?
Thanks to all

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to restore the state of search view widget:

Use below code to save the search query text:

```
private String mSearchQuery;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();

    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

  searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    if(mSearchQuery != null){
        searchView.setIconified(true);
        searchView.onActionViewExpanded();
        searchView.setQuery(mSearchQuery, false);
        searchView.setFocusable(true);
    }

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            mSearchQuery = newText;
            return false;
        }
    });

    return true;
}

 @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("searchQuery", mSearchQuery);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Then in OnCreate() method of activity, add following lines:

```
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        mSearchQuery = savedInstanceState.getString("searchQuery");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, replace your

```
mSearchView.setQuery(mSearchText, false);
```

with:

```
final String s = mSearchText;

mSearchView.post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mSearchView.setQuery(s, false);
    }
});
```

It will set the saved string after the system has set the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

There is better (in my opinion) way (without posting **Runnable**) to avoid setting query to **""** when you expand yours **SearchView**.

1) You will need one more **String** variable to store query.

```
//String that you fill in onQueryTextChange
String searchText;
//String, that is filled after you restore previous
String queryToSave;
```

2) After getting yours query from Bundle, store it in another variable.

```
if(this.searchText!=null)
{
    this.queryToSave=this.searchText;
}
```

3) In **onQueryTextChange(String query)** you fill **searchText** variable to text or to null if it's empty

4) In **onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item)** you need save yours restored String (**searchText**) to another variable (**queryToSave**), because it (**searchText**) will set to null after there will be call to **onQueryTextChange** with empty text

```
if(searchText!=null)
{
    queryToSave=new StringBuffer(searchText).toString();
}
```

5) So now if you call

```
mSearchView.setQuery(queryToSave, false);
```

after expanding **SearchView** **queryToSave** won't be empty and you'll see expanded **SearchView** with yours restored text!

Answer (score 0):

you should make this:

```
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private String mSearchString;
    private static final String SEARCH_KEY = "search";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // if you saved something on outState you can recover them here
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSearchString = savedInstanceState.getString(SEARCH_KEY);
        }
    }

    // This is called before the activity is destroyed
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mSearchString = mSearchView.getQuery().toString();
        outState.putString(SEARCH_KEY, mSearchString);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_main_action_search);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);

        //focus the SearchView
        if (mSearchString != null && !mSearchString.isEmpty()) {
            searchMenuItem.expandActionView();
            mSearchView.setQuery(mSearchString, true);
            mSearchView.clearFocus();
        }

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
}
```